# How to prevent that Foundation dropdown can be opened on disabled button?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, dropdownbox, disabled-control

I'm using the current version of Foundation.
I've implemented a content drop-down which I show on a button click.
The problem is: on some conditions I disable the button. In this case it shouldn't be possible to open the content drop-down.
But it's still possible to open the drop-down on click, even with the disabled button.

Is there any solution to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <button type="button" id="ptorEditDocuments" class="button pull-left button-center sm" data-dropdown="bl-document-edit-dropdown" aria-controls="bl-document-edit-dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Edit" ng-disabled="documents.length<1">
                            <i class="ic ic-edit-sm-blk"></i>
                        </button>
```

Solution was, that some controls were not right defined.
That was a fault of a previous implementation. I'm new to foundation and didn#t got it directly.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Really need to see some code or an example [pen](http://http:www.codepen.io). Have you tried using the prevent default function? event.preventDefault();